# Filling a line chart with D3.js (v4)

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

Trying to build a line chart and I have the following code.

```
var lineGraph = svgContainer.append('path')
    .attr('d', lineFunction(lineData))
    .attr('stroke', 'steelblue')
    .attr('stroke-width', 2)
    .attr('fill', 'red' );
```

I want to try and replace the `('fill', 'red')`with a fill that only fills from the line down. Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of a line generator, use an [area generator](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#area), which...

> ...Generates an area for the given array of data.

For instance, something like this:

```
var areaGenerator = d3.area()
  .x(function(d) {
    return d.x
  })
  .y1(function(d) {
    return d.y
  })
  .y0(function() {
    return someValue
  });
```

Where `someValue` in `y0` is the base of your area.

Here is a simple demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var data = d3.range(10).map(function(d) {
  return {
    x: d * 30 + 10,
    y: Math.random() * 130 + 10
  }
});

var areaGenerator = d3.area()
  .x(function(d) {
    return d.x
  })
  .y1(function(d) {
    return d.y
  })
  .y0(function() {
    return 150
  })
  .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX);

var area = svg.append('path')
  .attr('d', areaGenerator(data))
  .attr('stroke', 'steelblue')
  .attr('stroke-width', 2)
  .attr('fill', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

PS: The stroke ("steelblue") will be painted around **all** the path. That's probably not what you want. In that case, the fix is creating two paths: a path as you have right now, with the steelblue stroke and no fill, and the area that I showed in this answer, with no stroke and the red fill. Like this:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var data = d3.range(10).map(function(d) {
  return {
    x: d * 30 + 10,
    y: Math.random() * 130 + 10
  }
});

var areaGenerator = d3.area()
  .x(function(d) {
    return d.x
  })
  .y1(function(d) {
    return d.y
  })
  .y0(function() {
    return 150
  })
  .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX);

var lineGenerator = d3.area()
  .x(function(d) {
    return d.x
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return d.y
  })
  .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX);

var area = svg.append('path')
  .attr('d', areaGenerator(data))
  .attr('stroke-width', 2)
  .attr('fill', 'red');

var line = svg.append('path')
  .attr('d', lineGenerator(data))
  .attr('stroke', 'steelblue')
  .attr('stroke-width', 3)
  .attr('fill', 'none');
```

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```